# Django looking for static files in contrib/admin and ckeditor

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

My app doesn't serve the embedded static files in my HTML

my project structure is:

```
main/
mediafiles/
resume/
    settings.py
    ...
static/
    css/
    images/
    js/
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
"django.contrib.admin",
"django.contrib.auth",
"django.contrib.contenttypes",
"django.contrib.sessions",
"django.contrib.messages",
"django.contrib.staticfiles",
"main",
"ckeditor",
]
STARICFILES_DIR = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
]

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "mediafiles"
```

However, when I try `python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 static/js/style.js`
I get the following:

```
No matching file found for 'js/script.js'.

Looking in the following locations:
  C:\Users\Bilal\Envs\django-env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static
  C:\Users\Bilal\Envs\django-env\lib\site-packages\ckeditor\static
```

Any idea where I might be going wrong? All the static file settings appear to be correct.
Any help will be appreciated as I've been stuck on this one for a while

Comment: create after static  'app_name' i n your project structure. Than use 'app_name.file_name'.

Comment: Is your issue coming in deployment process or debug ==False